# how to use PHCachingImageManager().stopCachingImages

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I wish to fetch images from camera roll in collection view, and on selection i have to show selected image in full screen. So to achieve this i have used following code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell : ImagesCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImagesCell", for: indexPath) as! ImagesCell
    let asset = assets!.object(at: indexPath.row)
    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
    {
        (image, info) -> Void in
        cell.imageThumb.image = image
    }
    return cell
}
```

My screen looks like below :

[image: Photo1]

Now tap on a cell in didSelectRow delegate , i have to show image in full screen

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let asset = assets!.object(at: indexPath.row)
    guard (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.image) else {
        print("Not a valid image media type")
        return
    }

    //PHCachingImageManager().stopCachingImages(for: [asset], targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)

    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width:SCREENWIDTH(),height:SCREENHEIGHT()), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil)
    {
        (image, info) -> Void in
        runOnMainThreadWithoutDeadlock
        {
            let storybd = UIStoryboard(name: "MediaPicker", bundle: nil)
            let previewVC = storybd.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreviewViewController") as! PreviewViewController
            previewVC.selectedImage = image
            self.present(previewVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The screen looks like below :

[image: Photo2]

As you can see, the images appears blurred, i.e. it takes the cached image , i want to show full sized image, but i cannot find a way to do the same.

Please share if anyone have an idea, trying to find a way since long.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error :

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil) { (data, str, orientation, info) in
        let formAnImage = UIImage(data: data!)
        //you will get an original image
    }
```

The above option was not working perfectly for all cases, if user selects an older image, the data is nil , So i have used below solution :

```
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            options.isSynchronous = true
            options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.exact
            let targetSize = CGSize(width:SCREENWIDTH(), height:SCREENHEIGHT())

            PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFit, options: options) { (receivedImage, info) in

                if let formAnImage = receivedImage
                {
                    //You will get image here..
                }
            }
```